# Reading textfile and insert data into database

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

I have an exported text file that looks like this:

[Text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDBjq.png)

So it is built up like a table and it is unicode encoded. I don't create the export file, so please don't tell me to use csv files.

I already have a mariadb database in place with with a table that contains the respective headers (ID, Name, ..).

My goal is to read the data from the text file and insert it correctly into the daatabase. I am using node js and would like to know what steps i need to follow in order to accomplish my goal.

Can is use this instruction [URL](https://know-thy-code.com/importing-csv-data-mysql/)? I already tried it this way but i think the unicode encoding caused some problems.

Comment: what is your  exported file format? Is there any delimiter?

Comment: The exported file is a text file and the columns are delimited by a  single tab

Comment: Use the SQL statement `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using csv files to import/export any column related data, they have a tabular structure sort of implied from them.

Here in this case, you'll have to write some sort of a parser, which reads your file, one line at a time, then splits the data using multiple spaces as a delimiter, overall not really worth it.

Search into using csvs, there are even npm modules available for use with csv.

Answer (score 0):

So the way you would approach this is with streams. You would read each line into the buffer, parse it and save the data into the database.

Have a look at csv-stream library https://github.com/klaemo/csv-stream. It does the parsing for you and you can configure it to use tab as the delimiter.

```
const csv = require('csv-streamify')
const fs = require('fs')

const parser = csv({
  delimiter: '\t',
  columns: true,
});

// emits each line as a an object with keys as headers and properties as row values
parser.on('data', (line) => {
  console.log(line)
  // { ID: '1', Name: 'test', Date: '2010', State: 'US' }

  // Insert row into DB
  // ...
})

fs.createReadStream('data.txt').pipe(parser)
```

Comment: You can convert the text file into a tab-delimited csv file and use the above code. Alternatively you can parse the text file yourself in Node. If you upload an example of the file I can show you how to parse it

Comment: I've edited my answer after I've tested the code with your file example